# Как выполнить консольную команду в с++ через spawn?

Tags: c++, процесс

По задумке, нужно выполнить добавление/извлечение файла в архив/из архива с помощью функции spawn_posix, однако я не смог нигде найти достаточно понятного объяснение того как это работает :(
Надеюсь на вашу подсказку, или ссылки на ресурсы

Comment: Разделите свою задачу на две - запуск https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html и собственно подберите команду для распаковки

Comment: Саму доку по спавну я видел, но она крайне непонятна, сами команды для извлечения/добавления я знаю, меня лишь озадачивает сама непонятность работы функций семейства spawn

Comment: используйте boost.process

Comment: Надобно спавном, иначе бы я сам с радсотью условным System-ом справился

Comment: imho это какие-то сильно испорченные VAX/VMS (или уже виндой) люди придумали столь громоздкий интерфейс (spawn). Попробуйте все же посмотреть на [system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) или [popen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

Comment: Ну а в чем именно проблема? Просто если писать ответ на такой общий вопрос - это будет повтор документации,  он опять останется вам непонятен. Задайте более конкретный вопрос.